# Change Site Collection Home Link in Global Navigation

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a script using jQuery that allows me to change the Text of the Site Collection Root in the Global navigation. By default, I always set it to, "Home" using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.menu-item-text').first().text('Home');
</script>
```

The above code works great however, I notice that it's link always points to the root of the Site Collection and I need to change the link to point to the Root of my SharePoint Online Tenant.

How using jQuery can I replace the current link with a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.menu-item-text').first().attr('href','/your-link');
```